# Grow div till 100% according setInterval value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `setInterval()` inside a function. I'd like to create a status bar to show the user how much time is left until the `setInterval()` completes its time.

Any ideas how to do this? I tried but no success.

```js
function slideSwitch() {
  var myInterval = setTimeout(slideSwitch, 3000);
  var calc = myInterval / 30;
  $("#bottom_status").width(calc);
}

slideSwitch();
```

```css
#bottom_status {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottom_status"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpvfc582/

Comment: `myinterval` will be the id of the timer, so I'm not sure what output you're expecting when you divide it by `30`. You are also using `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()` as the title and question state

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought it was the time 0 to 3000. So divide it by 30 I cound grow my div using the value %. eg width: 80%

Comment: So the logic you're trying to create is to fill the progress bar over a span of 30 seconds - is that correct?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the span or div will start with 0 width. according timeout pass (from 0 to 3000 seconds) the div/span will grow to 100%. eg: timeout is in 1000 seconds, div is 33,3%width, time 2000 div 66,6%, time 3000 div 100%

Comment: What @RoryMcCrossan is saying is `myInterval` is not 3000. It is an id that the browser returns for that timeout. console.log(myInterval) will clearly show that.

Comment: CSS animation seems like it would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example based on your code ( The stop condition should be improved )

```js
progress = 0;
function slideSwitch() {


var myInterval = setTimeout(slideSwitch,100);
progress++;
var calc =  progress * 10;

if (progress > 100 ) clearInterval(myInterval);

$("#bottom_status").width(calc);

}

slideSwitch();
```

```css
#bottom_status{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=bottom_status></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little adjustements from [Vladu Ionut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4327861/vladu-ionut)'s answer:

```
var progress = 0;
function slideSwitch() {   
  var myInterval = setTimeout(slideSwitch,100);
  progress++;
  var calc =  progress * 10;

  if (progress > 100 ) { 
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    progress = 0;
    return;
  }

  $("#bottom_status").width(calc);    
}

slideSwitch();
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/dpvfc582/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use setInterval to update progressbar and clearInerval when the desidered time has passed

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var maxtime = 3000;
  var incremental = 500;
  var actualtime = 0;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    actualtime += incremental;
    var percentage = 100 / maxtime * actualtime;
    $("#bottom_status").width(percentage+"%");
    if (actualtime == maxtime) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, incremental)

}


slideSwitch();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hz916msb/

Answer (score 1):

A bit more dynamic and error-proof solution:

- No fixed widths to worry about
- Everything is calculated based on width
- Smooth 16 frames per second (variable)

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const status = document.getElementById('status');

let interval;

function slideSwitch(time) {
  const fps = 16;  
  const slice = wrapper.offsetWidth / (time / fps);
  let temp = status.offsetWidth;

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    temp = temp + slice;
    status.style.width = temp + 'px';
  }, fps);
  
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // TODO: switch your slide here
    
    clearInterval(interval);
    status.style.width = '0px';
  }, time);
}

slideSwitch(3000);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background: #eee;
}

#status {
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="status" />
</div>
```

Comment: I might have gone a little overboard.. [Fully functioning slider](https://jsfiddle.net/f4ycp05d/) in ~100 lines of JS.